# He wanted to have himself (get/be) devoured. --- Grammaticality

Tags: grammaticality

> "He wanted to have himself devoured."
>
> "He wanted to have himself be/get devoured."

I was reading an article, and I came across the sentence I used first of the sentences I used above.

And I was wondering if it's grammatically correct, and whether the second one would be deemed grammatically correct as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it's still grammatically correct, but it's getting needlessly wordy.

In general, it's better to make statements more concise rather than more wordy, particularly in writing.

Were you writing a blog post, this would be my suggested edit:

> *He wanted to be devoured*.

Comment: Or "to get devoured".  That's some blog.